# Class Iterator inside of container class

Tags: c++

I need to build an inner class iterator to work with a container class `FigureOfCircles`

```
#define T Circle
    class FigureOfCircles {
private:
    Circle* c;
    int size;
public:
    class Iterator {
    protected:
        T* t;
    public:
        explicit Iterator (T* t1 = 0) : t(t1) { }
        Iterator (const Iterator& x) : t(x.t)  {}
        T& operator*() const { return *t; }
        T* operator->() const { return t; }

        Circle& operator[](const std::size_t& n) { return t[n]; }
        Iterator& operator++() { ++t; return *this; }
        Iterator operator++(int) { return Iterator(t++); }

        Iterator& operator--() { --t; return *this; }
        Iterator operator--(int) { return Iterator(t--); }

        Iterator operator- (int n) { return Iterator(t - n); }
        Iterator operator+ (int n) { return Iterator(t - n); }

        Iterator& operator-= (int n) { t -= n; return *this; }
        Iterator& operator+= (int n) { t += n; return *this; }

        bool operator== (const Iterator& x) const { return t == x.t; }
        bool operator!= (const Iterator& x) const { return t != x.t; }
        bool operator<= (const Iterator& x) const { return t <= x.t; }
        bool operator> (const Iterator& x) const { return t > x.t; }
        bool operator>= (const Iterator& x) const { return t >= x.t; }
        bool operator< (const Iterator& x) const { return t < x.t; }
        friend int operator- (const Iterator& x, const Iterator& y) { return x.t - y.t; }

        Iterator& operator= (const Iterator& x) {
            if (t == x.t) exit(-6);
            t = x.t;
            return *this;
        }
    };

    FigureOfCircles (int sz) : size(sz) {
        c = new T[size];
        for (Iterator i = begin(); i != end(); ++i) *i = input();
    }
    FigureOfCircles(const FigureOfCircles& f) {
        size = f.size;
        c = new T[size];
        for (Iterator i = begin(); i != end(); ++i) *i = f.c[i - begin()];
    }
    ~FigureOfCircles() { if (c) delete[] c; }

    Circle input() {
        int size = 1;
        Point* arr = new Point[size];
        float r, x1, y1;
        cout << endl << "Введiть к-сть точок, радiус i координати центру: ";
        cin >> size >> r >> x1 >> y1;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            Point tmp;
            cin >> tmp;
            if (tmp.GetX() == x1 && tmp.GetY() == y1) exit(-7);
            if (pow(tmp.GetX() - x1, 2) + pow(tmp.GetY() - y1, 2) != r * r) exit(-8);
            arr[i] = tmp;
        }
        return Circle(size, r, arr, x1, y1);        
    }

    Iterator begin() { return Iterator(c); }
    Iterator end() { return Iterator(c+size); }
};
```

But I don’t understand what type should T be so that I can use the iterator object? If it is `int`, then what about

```
Iterator begin() { return Iterator(c); }
Iterator end() { return Iterator(c+size); }
```

> Note:

```
FigureOfCircles (int sz) : size(sz) {
    c = new T[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        c[i].input();
    for (Iterator i = begin(); i != end(); ++i) {
        *i = T(i-begin());
    }
}
```

> ...

```
 int main () {
    //...
    FigureOfCircles f(2);
    FigureOfCircles::Iterator i;
    for (i = f.begin(); i != f.end(); i++) cout << *i << endl;
    }
```

Comment: If `c` is a pointer to an array of `Circle`s (to the first element), then `T` in `Iterator` should be `Circle`, so that `T* = Circle*` is a pointer to elements of this array. Your `begin()` and `end()` function are correct.

Comment: @Egg I get an error at this line `for (Iterator i = begin(); i != end(); ++i) *i = f.c[i - begin()];` cause it doesn't make any sense to access `c` with its own object. Do I need to overload `operator[ ]` or what ?

Comment: Answered in the answers section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an array of `Circle`s, pointed by `c`. An iterator should point to elements of this array. The simplest solution is to use a plain pointer. That is, `T` in your iterator should be just `Circle`.

If you want to use `int` (it should be `std::ptrdiff_t`), your iterator should also keep a pointer to the first element. In this particular example I don't see a reason to do it.

`operator-` should return the difference between pointers, `std::ptrdiff_t`, not `Circle`:

```
friend std::ptrdiff_t operator-(Iterator x, Iterator y) { 
    return x.t - y.t;
}
```

Take `Iterator` by value. It's just a single pointer, you don't need to take it by const-ref (effectively taking a pointer to a pointer).

Once you have iterators, you can use the standard library algorithms to make copies: instead of

```
for (Iterator i = begin(); i != end(); ++i) *i = f.c[i - begin()];
```

you can write

```
std::copy(f.begin(), f.end(), begin());
```

---

I suggest you use `std::vector<Circle>` instead of `Circle*`. Then you'll be able to borrow its iterators:

```
class FigureOfCircles {
private:
    std::vector<Circle> c;
public:
    std::vector<Circle>::iterator begin() {
        c.begin();
    }

    std::vector<Circle>::iterator end() {
        c.end();
    }
};
```

This will also save you from writing a copy constructor and destructor.

Comment: It doesn't do quite what I expect. I have an array of Circle objects and I need to perform some further manipulations with it. But how do I fill this array with objects using or not using iterator?

Comment: @Llor1s, without iterator you loop with `std::size_t` index, with iterator you loop with iterator itself. Your updated code will not compile. For example, what is `delete[i] arr;`?

Comment: @Llor1s, please don't modify the code in your question. Add new code below. Otherwise people who are going to find it later won't understand what the answers are about.

Comment: What about now?

Comment: @Llor1s, sorry but I don't understand what the question really is. The part that uses the iterator looks correct. Instead of `f.c[i - begin()]`, I'd prefer two iterators, one over `c`, another over `f.c`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203449/discussion-between-evg-and-llor1s).

Comment: See the note plz. I get zeros from `cout << *i` when I input `c`.

Answer (score 1):

While @Evg's answer is valid, it is not clear from your question why would even need to write your own iterator. If, instead of a pair of pointer+length members, you would use an `std::vector` or `std::array` - or even `std::span` which is oblivious to where you get your buffer from - you could use these classes' respective iterators instead of implementing your own.

It is only if you have some special behavior in your `FigureOfCircles` class - e.g. element skipping, non-standard iteration order and so on - that you really need a custom iterator.

PS - The naming is a bit awkward. If a Figure can only have Circles, then just call the class `Figure`. If there are Figures of something other than Circles, try: `template <typename Element> class Figure { ... }` and then you'll use `Figure<Circle>`.